# How doest Trello store generated actions from updates to other documents (boards, cards) in MongoDB without atomic transactions?

Tags: mongodb, event-sourcing, trello

I'm developing a single page web app that will use a NoSQL Document Database (like MongoDB) and I want to generate events when I make a change to my entities.

Since most of these databases support transactions only on a document level (MongoDB just added ASIC support) there is no good way to store changes in one document and then store events from those changes to other documents.

Let's say for example that I have a collection 'Events' and a collection 'Cards' like Trello does. When I make a change to the description of a card from the 'Cards' collection, an event 'CardDescriptionChanged' should be generated.

The problem is that if there is a crash or some error between saving the changes to the 'Cards' collection and adding the event in the 'Events' collection this event will not be persisted and I don't want that.

I've done some research on this issue and most people would suggest that one of several approaches can be used:

1. Do not use MongoDB, use SQL database instead (I don't want that)
2. Use Event Sourcing. (This introduces complexity and I want to clear older events at some point, so I don't want to keep all events stored. I now that I can use snapshots and delete older events from the snapshot point, but there is a complexity in this solution)
3. Since errors of this nature probably won't happen too often, just ignore them and risk having events that won't be saved (I don't want that too)
4. Use an event/command/action processor. Store commands/action like 'ChangeCardDescription' and use a Processor that will process them and update the entities.

I have considered option 4, but a couple of question occurs:

- How do I manage concurrency?

I can queue all commands for the same entity (like a card or a board) and make sure that they are processed sequentially, while events for different entities (different cards) can be processed in parallel. Then I can use processed commands as events. One problem here is that changes to an entity may generate several events that may not correspond to a single command. I will have to break down to very fine-grained commands all user actions so I can then translate them to events.

- Error reporting and error handling.

If this process is asynchronous, I have to manage error reporting to the client. And also I have to remove or mark commands that failed.

- I still have the problem with marking the commands as processed, as there are no transactions. I know I have to make processing of commands idempotent to resolve this problem.

Since Trello used MongoDB and generates actions ('DeleteCardAction', 'CreateCardAction') with changes to entities (Cards, Boards..) I was wondering how do they solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new collection called `FutureUpdates`. Write planned updates to the `FutureUpdates` collection with a single document defining the changes you plan to make to cards and the events you plan to generate. This insert will be atomic.

Now take a `[ChangeStream][1]` of the `FutureUpdates` collection this will give you the stream of updates you need to make. Take each doc from the change stream and apply the updates. Finally, update the doc in `FutureUpdates` to mark it as complete. Again this update will be atomic.

When you apply the updates to Events and Cards make sure to include the objectID of the doc used to create the update in `FutureUpdates`.

Now if the program crashes after inserting the update in `FutureUpdates` you can check the Events and Cards collections for the existence of records containing the objectID of the update. If they are not present then you can reapply the missing updates.

If the updates have been applied but the `FutureUpdate` doc is not marked as complete we can update that during recovery to complete the process.

Effectively you are continuously atomically updating a doc for each change in `FutureUpdates` to track progress. Once an update is complete you can archive the old docs or just delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of doing something like this. I was thinking of using something like a CQRS system where there are multiple models but discard changes of the wire model. I was wondering are there any other solutions simpler than this that I may be missing. Since Trello solved it (and i like their system) i was wondering how they did it :)